# Преобразование URL запроса на кириллице (русском) в запрос на Английском

Tags: java, android, json, url

Я разрабатываю погодное андроид приложение, и столкнулся с проблемой при отправке и получении **JSON** файла, для получения конкретных данных в URL-запрос нужно вставить название города **на английском**.

*Пример:*

```
http:/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=**ГОРОД (на английском)**&appid=**API КЛЮЧ**&units=metric
```

Но пользователь вводит название города на **русском** и соответственно сайт выдает ошибку, ибо воспринимает только **английские** символы.

**Вопрос:**

**Каким образом можно преобразовать русские символы в английские при отправке URL-запроса?**

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: эм, в смысле латиницей?
типа:
Челябинск -> Chelyabinsk ?

Comment: лучше выпадающий список сделать, типа так [title: 'челябинск', val: 'Chelyabinsk',...] . И пользователь бы просто выбирал из выпадающего списка значение, а в URL передавалось бы значение val

Comment: Звучит как-то сложновато, мне достаточно просто введеную строку переобразовать в латиницу.

Comment: У меня нет списка городов, API супер простое, в него лишь передается город (латиницей) и API ключ.

Comment: ну все таки списки надежней будут) ну можно найти какой нибудь простой транслитератор ) только велик шанс нарваться на ситуцию что на русском город будет Челябинск а API ожидает Chelabinsk  а не Chelyabinsk

Comment: API ожидает именно Chelyabinsk.

Comment: ну я как пример) разные же вариации бывают) и какое название ожидает API неизвестно, по этому поэтому и автоматическое преобразование надо делать аккуратней)
если не хотите использовать списки лучше разрешить ввод только латиницей ) ( ну как вариант )

ну и в подсказке указать мол вводить город латиницей

Comment: Не плохая идея, возьму на заметку.

Comment: А что API не хочет кириллицу? Было бы проще закодировать её в URL-encoding, чем извращаться с транслитом.

Comment: @Archieq подскажите, пожалуйста, как именно выглядит ошибка? Я точно знаю, что данное API прекрасно работает с кириллицей

Comment: @Archieq просто вставьте URL запрос в браузер с любым городом, название которого написано на латинице, не забудьте вставить в URL ваш ключ, и поделитесь, пожалуйста тем, что выведет браузер. Ошибка по-видимому, в другом, так как у меня ошибок не возникает, только что проверил

Comment: В последнем комментарии ошибка: название которого написано на кириллице